# Selenium standalone server jar file hangs

Tags: java, selenium

I'm having an issue running the Selenium standalone server -- it just hangs partway through loading. I've tried several different versions of the standalone server but the same issue arises. From the command line I run...

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar
```

And get back...

```
Oct 16, 2012 8:29:34 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a standalone server
20:29:40.190 INFO - Java: Apple Inc. 20.10-b01-428
20:29:40.193 INFO - OS: Mac OS X 10.7.4 x86_64
20:29:40.202 INFO - v2.25.0, with Core v2.25.0. Built from revision 17137
20:29:40.322 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
20:29:40.324 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
20:29:40.324 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
20:29:40.326 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
20:29:40.326 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
20:29:40.376 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@1f8b81e3
20:29:40.377 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
20:29:40.382 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
20:29:40.383 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@4ee1d5ea
```

Comment: seems that everything works fine - whats the issue? did you check if its running by calling http://127.0.0.1:4444 in your web browser?

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I just needed to open another command line console to run perl and keep running the jar file in the background. I was going to delete the question -- but there are probably other boneheads out there who this will save a half hour.

Answer (score 0):

If the comment does not help, try changing start command to

```
java -jar lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -role hub
```

(It is command for starting Selenium Grid, so it might be wrong for you, but I dont know what are you trying to achieve)

And as mentioned above, after the command is run

1. DO NOT CLOSE COMMAND LINE
2. Open browser and load `http://127.0.0.1:4444/`

You should see something like this:

You are using grid 2.25.0
Find help on the official selenium wiki : [more help here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2)

default monitoring page : console